# vscode keeps telling me nullptr is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm writing C++ in VSCode. The `nullptr` is marked by red cursive line and showing `identifier "nullptr" is undefined`. Though, I can run this code perfectly with code-runner extension. But how do I get rid of this false alert in VSCode?

[image: lpt]

Comment: maybe change the C++ version in `c_cpp_properties.json`

Comment: Show contents of your __c_cpp_properties.json__ please.

Comment: @Aleksey Thank you so much. It is in the file indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is pointed in the comments, in the project folder, just find `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file and change the C++ version to C11. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue previously. I tried only adding these two lines:

```
#include <iostream>
#using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::cin;
```

warning disappeared

Comment: This might have worked, but OP had some other issue, which was resolved in another way.